# Analysis of continuity of $f(x)$ at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, functions

Given that

$f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+ n \cdot (\sin x)^2}$ then comment on continuity at $x=0$.

$f(0)=1/(1+0)=1$ but how to find $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$ because in denominator it is indeterminate form of $0 \times \infty$

Comment: There is no indeterminate form. You can directly show that $f(x) = 0$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: [Cont'd from previous comment] and $|x| < \pi$

Answer (score 2):

If $|x|< \pi$ and $x \neq 0$, then $\sin x \neq 0$.

for such $x$, $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+n (\sin x)^2}=0$

Remark:

It might appear that the function looks scary, but it can be rewritten in the form of

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} a & , \sin(x)=0 \\b &, \sin(x) \neq 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: $x$ is fixed when we take limit of $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: For example, if $x = \frac{\pi}{6}$, $\sin^2 x = 0.25$, then we can evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+0.25n}$

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

$f_n(x): =\dfrac{1}{1+n(\sin x)^2}$.

$f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(x),$  I.e.

pointwise convergence.

Consider a small neighbourhood of $x=0.$

Say: $|x| \lt π/6.$

1) $x=0:$ $f(0) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n(0) =1.$

2) $x\not=0$:  $f(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) =0;$

Hence:

$f(x) = 1$, $x= 0$ and

$f(x) = 0$, $x \not= 0.$

$f$ is not continuos at $x=0.$